# jQuery accessing JSON Data in HTML data element returns undefined when accessing keys

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, undefined, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to get some pins to show up on a google map when a graphic is clicked. I am storing all the data I need in a data-location element on my span tag:

```
<span class="showOnMap" data-location="{"lat":"51.4894805","lng":"-0.2942533000000367","name":"Brentford Towers","addr":"Green Dragon Lane\r\nBrentford TW8 0DF","pinType":"loc"}">    <img width="32" height="32" src="/images/Icons/map-icon.png">
</span>
```

my click function is:

```
$('.showOnMap').click(function(){
    //alert('click');
    var myData = $(this).data('location');
    console.log(myData);
    createMarkerWithInfo(myData);
    //addToPanel(panelData);
 })
```

The function to create the marker is causing me a problem the data passed to it shows up as undefined when I alert it, or try to use it to create the markers, it does however show up in console, but from what I've been reading the console shouldn't be trusted in this as it will show the data at its current state, i.e it might not of been defined when the actual call to console was made,

I don't understand why its undefined as The JSON data is in the DOM (its actually generated by PHP) so is defined in the DOM, I could understand if I was doing an Ajax call why it might come up as undefined.

```
function createMarkerWithInfo(myData){
        //console.log(myData);
        //coords = myData.latlng.split(','); 
        alert(myData + 'pinType: '+ myData.pinType + ' lat: '+ myData.lat + ' lng: ' +myData.lng);
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(myData.lat, myData.lng);  
        if(myData.pinType == 'loc'){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: myData.name,     
                icon: locimage,
                shadow: locshadow,
                shape: locshape
            });
        }
        if(myData.pinType == 'ub'){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: myData.name,     
                icon: ubimage,
                shadow: ubshadow,
                shape: locshape
            });
        }
        //alert('lat: '+myData.lat+','+'lng: '+myData.lng);
        // Wrapping the event listener inside an anonymous function
        // that we immediately invoke and passes the variable i to.
        (function(myData, marker) {
            // Creating the event listener. It now has access to the values of
            // myData and marker as they were during its creation
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                //create thecontent for the infowindow
                var content = createContent(myData);
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            
        })(myData, marker);     
        markersArray.push(marker);
        markersPosArray.push(myLatLng);
        bounds.extend(myLatLng);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        zoomMarkers();
    }
```

http://2012.reelfilmlocations.co.uk/Modules/builder_areaLocs.php
is the page I am working on, whats strange is i have a similar page (uses PHP includes rather than a standalone page) which has the same functions and it works, I've looked at both and cant see a difference as too what is causing it to be undefined).

http://2012.reelfilmlocations.co.uk/locations-london-west/

Comment: Terminology:  You don't make Ajax calls to the DOM.  Ajax is server/client communication.

Comment: From the jquery .data() doc `Regarding HTML5 data-* attributes: This low-level method does NOT retrieve the data-* attributes unless the more convenient .data() method has already retrieved them.`  Consider using [jquery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the json was wrapped in `[ ]` tags.

`alert(myData + 'pinType: '+ myData[0].pinType + ' lat: '+ myData[0].lat + ' lng: ' +myData[0].lng);`

Outputs the correct values.